# WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type T with qualifiers @Default

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, subclassing, weld

I got 2 beans.

The first one is the model I use in production, `Model`.

```
@Named("model")
@RequestScoped
public class Model{

}
```

The second one is the extension of `Model` that I use for testing.

```
@Named("modelTest")
@RequestScoped
public class ModelTest extends Model{

}
```

How can I force CDI to select `Model` by default?

Comment: A test shouldn't extend the class it tests anyway.

Comment: its not a junit test. its a different test. custom test for web components. but it shouldnt matter. because this problem would arise if i simply had 2 implementations of an interface.

Comment: Take a look at [https://dzone.com/articles/java-ee6-cdi-named-components ]

Comment: Egl, a qualifier is not necessary here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to change the 'default' bean for given type and you don't want to use qualifiers, I assume the original bean is not to be injected anywhere. Therefore, what you are probably after is either an **alternative or a specialization.**

If we talk about **alternatives**, you need to mark the new bean with `@Alternative` annotation and also 'select' it - that can be done on a per bean archive basis in `beans.xml` or simply globally with `@Priority(int)`. Here is a code snippet:

```
@Named("modelTest")
@RequestScoped
@Alternative
@Priority(1) // "activates"/selects the alternative
public class ModelTest extends Model{
}
```

With a selected alternative, whenever you inject the previous type (`Model`), CDI will instead inject this alternative (`ModelTest`), as it fits the injection point as well.

Secondary option is **specialization**. It is very similar to alternatives but stricter in a way that the original bean is 'discarded', you can read more about that in [CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#specialization). Specialization also comes with qualifier and bean name inheritance (*not the scope though!)*. There is also no need to select the bean (as opposed to alternatives). Here is the code:

```
@RequestScoped
@Specializes
public class ModelTest extends Model{
  // bean name with be inherited automatically as "model"
}
```

Note that a bean can only have one bean name at a time, as per specification. Therefore if you inherit one name and declare another, you will be getting errors - alter your code accordingly.